# How to display data from the database in select option?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can succesfully get the data from my database , but how can I display it Inside the Select?

This is where i want to display my data inside the select

```
<Select
    fullWidth
    value={newUsers}
    onChange={handleChange}
>
<MenuItem value={0}>{newUsers.label}</MenuItem>
```

this is how i call the data from the database (this is working and I can see the data from my console)

```
  const [newUserLists, setNewUserLists] =useState([]);
  const newUsers= [];
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await getreason();
    response.data.map(function(u){
      newUsers.push({
         label: u.applicationcode,
         value: u.applicationid
      })
    })
    setNewUserLists(newUsers)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [reRender]);
```

this is the result in console.log

[image]

Comment: Are you using material-ui? It's difficult for anyone to answer without the proper context of where `Select` and `MenuItem` are coming from. You can add tags to the question and/or be more explicit in the title/body text

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I used material-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's model this on the [Material-UI Select tutorial](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) and [API doc page](https://material-ui.com/api/select/). There, we can see a few things:

- `value` is the currently selected input value. It appears you're trying to set it to the list of objects that you read from the DB response, which is not correct. It is common practice to say something like the following:

```js
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel>Selection</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {/* MenuItems go here */}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
```

- On an unrelated (to Material-UI) note, you seem to not actually use `newUserLists` in your code. I'm going to make the assumption that `newUsers` is just a placeholder to munge the data from the response into, but per @Naim-Mustafa's answer, it isn't needed and should not be used in your display.
- Now, how do we use `newUsersList` to generate a list of `MenuItem`s? Just as you've done elsewhere, `map` is the key:

```js
        {newUsersList.map(({ label, value }) => (
          <MenuItem id={value} value={value}>
            {label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
```

Note that I'm assuming `value` is unique for the purposes of the `id` field. If it is not, replace with something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `const newUsers= [];` to `let newUsers= [];`

but you dont have to use newUsers array at all, instead try using the state

```
const [newUserLists, setNewUserLists] =useState([]);
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState();
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await getreason();
    
    setNewUserLists(response.data.map(user => ({
         label: user.applicationcode, 
         value: user.applicationid})))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [reRender]);


return (
<>
       <select value={selectedOption}
         onChange={(event) => setSelectedOption(event.target.value)}
         >
         {newUserLists
                 .map(user => 
                <option key={user.label} value={user.label}> 
                {user.label}</option>}
        </select>
</>
```

Comment: Can you please complete this `<select ...props>`

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: sorry thats the classic select html tag, ive updated now